Firebase Background Notifications Not Getting Handled on iOS Flutter
I am working on FCM with Flutter. In case of Android it is working fine. But, in case of iOS, it is not working as expected. I am receiving both background and foreground notifications. Foreground notifications are getting handled and working as expected. But, in case of background notifications, I am receiving them, but they are not getting handled. Following is my Flutter code:
class FirebaseNotificationManager {
 static Future<void> initFirebaseNotifications() async {
  ...
  ...
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
 }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    debugPrint("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
    debugPrint('Message data: ${message.data}');
    debugPrint('Message notification: ${message.notification?.title}');
    debugPrint('Message notification: ${message.notification?.body}');

    // Further operations
  }
}

I've added 'Push Notification' and 'Background Modes' Capabilities. I've also added necessary key in Project Settings in Firebase.
I've set FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled: false in Info.plist.

Modify AppDelegate.swift ->  method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
